# kube-prometheus-stack Out of sync to Unknown in ArgoCD

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, grafana, argocd

I am using the non HA version of ArgoCD (v2.6.5) installed in a single node k3s cluster.
The goal is to deploy a sample application together with kube-prometheus-stack, loki, tempo & minIO via Helm.

However, when I create an "Application" in Github and reference it in Argocd, all of them are in "Out of sync" state. Once it tries to re-sync, they change the status to "Unknown".

The installation of ArgoCD was done with the next command. (Basic install)

```
kubectl create namespace argocd
kubectl apply -n argocd -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/argoproj/argo-cd/stable/manifests/install.yaml
```

And, as example, the kube-prometheus-stack Application I create in Github looks this way:

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: kube-prometheus-stack
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  project: default
  source:
    chart: kube-prometheus-stack
    repoURL: https://prometheus-community.github.io/helm-charts
    targetRevision: 44.4.1
    helm:
      releaseName: kube-prometheus-stack
  destination:
    server: "https://kubernetes.default.svc"
    namespace: observability
```

Any idea what I could be missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:

```
FROM repoURL: https://prometheus-community.github.io/helm-charts
TO   repoURL: git@github.com:prometheus-community/helm-charts.git
OR   repoURL: https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts.git
```

```
FROM targetRevision: 44.4.1 
TO   targetRevision: kube-prometheus-stack-44.4.1
```

And under the *targetRevision* field, add:

```
path: charts/kube-prometheus-stack
```

Comment: Of course I assume that:
1. your single node can reach github
2. ArgoCD has been successfully installed
3. use the values.yaml Chart default file (kube-prometheus-stack)

Comment: I run into the same issue after making those changes. With more investigation I found out that one of the issues comes from the CRDs. I need to apply them separately so ArgoCD does not fail in the reapply.

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed by deploying the CRDs separately. There seem to be more issues with a few objects and CRDs within the kube-prometheus-stack and loki charts, however, I can close this one.